# Как сделать рутинг в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте!

Как с помощью nginx сделать так, чтобы при запросе `example.com/forum/5` открывалось `example.com/forum.php?id=5`?
При этом надо, чтобы при запросе `example.com/forum/` открывалась другая страница(скажем, `example.com/f.php`).

Спасибо.

Comment: По-хорошему этим должен заниматься ваш php-код

Answer (score 2):

Помог код:
`rewrite ^/forum/([0-9]+)?$ /forum.php?id=$1 last;`.
Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
location /forum/[0-9]+ {
    rewrite ^/.* http://example.com/forum.php?id=5 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как реализовать такое же, только с регулярным выражением (0-9+)?

Comment: Ну а почему в вопросе сразу этого не было? Добавил регулярку [0-9]+ Она означает, что в этом месте должна быть цифра от 0 до 9, а знак `+` означает одно или более повторений.

Comment: Извините, но как сделать, чтобы id было не 5 всегда, а значение из [0-9]+?